# is nginx caching working?

Tags: nginx, cache

I can't tell if nginx is caching properly. I am running a MEAN stack app with nginx in front as a (hopefully) caching reverse proxy.

1. If I use the chrome dev tools networking tab, it has a response header: X-Powered-By Express.
2. If I do curl -I mysite.com it says 302 moved temporarily and Server: nginx/version. I'm confused as to whether or not express or nginx is serving the request.

I took a look at my server's console and it gives 304 for every request.

Here is my config in sites-available/default. nginx.config is the default.

```
proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m
    inactive=24h  max_size=1g;

server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_cache             STATIC;
                proxy_cache_valid       200 1d;
                add_header      cache_status    $upstream_cache_status;
            }
}
```

cache_status header doesn't show up with hit, miss or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Look in

```
/data/nginx/cache
```

to see if there's any files there.

I have a tutorial on Nginx which includes caching [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/). I don't think you have all required settings, unless some have defaults, like

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Inside your location you could need this, if headers aren't set appropriately by the app you're caching

```
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
```

Read the tutorial, it gives more tips. Earlier parts of the tutorial show you how to build Nginx from source, which lets you do things like compile in mod_headers, which is handy to add headers for debugging.